# ASP Web API Kendo UI Grid value cannot be null: entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using the Grid component from Kendo UI on my Web API application. My records are being loaded correctly and even the delete is working, but unfortunately the **Post** and **Update** are not working. I got the error message on the response of the request: message: "An error has occurred.", exceptionMessage: "Value cannot be null. ↵Parameter name: entity",…}

Bellow part of my view and controller. What am I missing? Trying lots of things. *The field names are lower case because I'm using CamelCase.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/api/products",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: function (data) {
                    return "/api/products/" + data.id;
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "PUT"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: function (data) {
                    return "/api/products/" + data.id;
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "DELETE"
            },
            create: {
                url: "/api/products",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        batch: false,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    name: { validation: { required: true } },
                    description: { validation: { required: true } }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 550,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            { field: "name", title: "Name" },
            { field: "description", title: "Description" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" 
        }],
        editable: "popup"
    });
```

And this is part of my controller and repository:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
{
    var products = _productRepository.GetProducts();
    return Ok(products);
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateProduct(Product product)
{
    _productRepository.CreateProduct(product);
    _productRepository.SaveProduct();

    return Ok();
}

[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateProduct(int id, Product product)
{
    var productInDb = _productRepository.GetProduct(id);

    if (productInDb == null)
        return NotFound();

    _productRepository.UpdateProduct(product);
    _productRepository.SaveProduct();

    return Ok();
}


public Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    return _context.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
}

public void CreateProduct(Product product)
{
    _context.Products.Add(product);
}

public void UpdateProduct(Product product)
{
    _context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public void SaveProduct()
{
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**UPDATE**
I think parameterMap function was wrong in the first place because when Posting or Updating it was never entering in the condition, so here it goes the parameterMap updated. The POST worked after that change (it's not just closing the window and repopulating the grid, I don't know why). **But unfortunately** the Update is still not working as I receive the following error inside controller *"Attaching an entity of type 'Models.Product' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. "*. What am I missing in this situation?

```
parameterMap: function (options) {
    return kendo.stringify(options);
},
type: "json"
```

Comment: I do not see ***update*** and ***destroy*** in ***transport***. In addition, I do not see ***HttpPut*** and ***HttpDelete*** in Web API Controller. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I just put the create and httppost, but I have them in my code. I thought create and httppost was enough. If needed I will edit my question with the rest of the code.

Comment: You said ***Update*** is not working, but you show us ***Create*** code. Please kindly reword the question and update with appropriate code.

Comment: Create and Update are not working, so you're right, I updated my question with the other methods.

Comment: It seems that exceptionMessage is thrown from Entity Framework - inserting null to a column which doesn't allow null value.

Comment: The only fields that are not not-null are id, name and description. They are being displayed correctly on the grid. The create method shouldn't require id, I suppose, and I'm filling name and description during the create.

Comment: Could you set a break point inside HttpPost CreateProduct method and step through?

Comment: I added a breakpoint in the HttpPost controller and you're right, product is null. But would you know why kendo is not passing the data? I mean, what am I missing?

Comment: I found out that when Posting, it was never entering the parameterMap condition and setting the models. So I changed it, but it still doesn't work as my HttpPost controller is receiving product null. I updated my question. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you take out `parameterMap: function () {...}` and try again?

Comment: In fact, I did another change to the parameterMap and it worked posting data. The only problem is that after posting, the window is not closing and grid not updating. Also, the HttPut is still not working. I updated my question in section **UPDATE**, please could you have a look? Thank you

Comment: After your latest update u have a different question that your original.  Your 2nd issue is that you are passing in an entity from the client with id of '1'. You then pull the actual entity out of the database (productInDb) with the same id.  EF has change tracking set on that entity. You then try and update the state of the first entity but EF correctly tells you, "hey I already have that entity in memory, sorry charlie." You need to map the properites of your view model to the entity in the db and then update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with the help in the comments (basically the main problem was the parameterMap, and then a fill tweeks were needed as well as passing back the entity in the return of the controller methods). I'm putting the updated code below (only the part that was changed).

View:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/api/products",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: function (data) {
                    return "/api/products/" + data.id;
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "PUT"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: function (data) {
                    return "/api/products/" + data.id;
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "DELETE"
            },
            create: {
                url: "/api/products",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options) {
                return kendo.stringify(options);
            },
            type: "json"
        },
        batch: false,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    name: { validation: { required: true } },
                    description: { validation: { required: true } }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 550,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            { field: "name", title: "Name" },
            { field: "description", title: "Description" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" 
        }],
        editable: "popup"
    });
```

Controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
{
    var products = _productRepository.GetProducts();
    return Ok(products);
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateProduct(Product product)
{
    _productRepository.CreateProduct(product);
    _productRepository.SaveProduct();

    return Ok(product);
}

[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateProduct(int id, Product product)
{
    _productRepository.UpdateProduct(product);
    _productRepository.SaveProduct();

    return Ok(product);
}
```